# MySQL Update Multiple Rows to Increment Values Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple rows on one table using MySQL. I have found that this is possible but I am trying to increment the value of the comments column by a given amount, however trying to increment it by 1 actually increments it by 3.

```
$increment = 1;
('UPDATE articles
SET comments = CASE
WHEN article_id in(1, 2) THEN comments + ' . $increment . '
END');
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Obviously the update statement is run twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE articles SET comments = comments + " . $increment . " WHERE article_id IN (1, 2)";
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has the same result, however it only seems to happen when the initial value it is changing is 0 (zero).

Comment: Have you verified that that values are what you think they are before you run the query? Or you call the script more than once etc...?

Comment: Right I'm off to bury my head in the sand ha! I was calling the script more than once! Obviously too logical for me to realise! Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I can't really see why your current query isn't working, but what happens when you use this query?

```
UDPATE 
    articles 
SET 
    comments=comments+'.$increment.'
WHERE
    article_id IN (1,2)
```